# why generic type arrow function shows error?

Tags: typescript, react-native

Why this is not working ?

```
const List: <ListItem> = ({ items, render }: {
  items: ListItem[],
  render: (item: ListItem) => React.ReactNode
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      { items.map((el, i) => (
        <Text key={i}>{render(el)}</Text>
      )) }
    </View>
  )
};
```

Error:

```
TransformError SyntaxError: C:\RNT\TS\ts\App.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "(" (54:23)
```

Comment: `<ListItem>` is not a valid type annotation. If you explained what was that code trying to do, maybe we could help more.

Comment: I want to use a generic list

Comment: So, just move the generic annotation to the other side of `=`. You should also checked [the documentation on generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax. A generic function has it's generic parameter just before the opening `(` character.

That would probably look like this:

```
const List = <ListItem>({ items, render }: {
  items: ListItem[],
  render: (item: ListItem) => React.ReactNode
}) => {
  //...
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=8&ssc=3&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gBlg64BeOAHkboEkYkQAfAAoA3nGB8QNADRwiVACZIocAL4AuOCNJxxkmpq4xe-ANoBdaTrlJFyzUIn9DTY5ICUrAYmIwAdMjoMAByEEqkqp4s3tq6APRxfkkRANxAA)